# MongoDbConnector publish multiple collections to only topic Kafka

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Below is my MongoDbConnector configuration:

```json
{
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
  "collection.include.list": "dbname.messages,dbname.comments",
  "mongodb.password": "mongodbpassword",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "database.history.kafka.topic": "dev.dbhistory.unwrap_with_key_id_8",
  "mongodb.user": "mongodbuser",
  "heartbeat.interval.ms": "90000",
  "mongodb.name": "analytics",
  "snapshot.delay.ms": "120000",
  "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "poll.interval.ms": "3000",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "mongodb.authsource": "admin",
  "errors.tolerance": "all",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "mongodb.hosts": "rs0/ip:27017",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "database.include.list": "dbname",
  "snapshot.mode": "initial"
}
```

I need this publish to only topic, but it create two topic is **analytics.dbname.messages** and **analytics.dbname.messages**. How can i do?

My english is not good! Thanks!

Comment: Typo? You put `analytics.dbname.messages` twice in your question

Comment: If you only want one topic, have you tried removing `dbname.comments` from the include list and only use messages collection?